# My attempt at ProjectEuler #1

Tags: beginner, c

The task for Project Euler #1 is to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Here's what I coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int size=1000, i=0, sum=0;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (i%3==0 || i%5==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 233168

Note that I didn't assign `main()` to return an `int` data type. I know this is not valid C, but my compiler ignores this. I'm a lazy person; I like to type less. Not typing `int` before `main()`, when coding *casually*, saves me time and effort (also memory!). I'm well-aware of the fact, though.

Comment: What  exactly do you think is _bizarre_ about these different results? `232169 + 999` yields  `233168` when I put  that in my procket calculator.

Comment: 1000 is just one more number taken into consideration. If it is divisible by either 3 or 5, the result should be be plus 1.

Comment: In your loop  `i` will be `0 - 999` if `size` is `1000`. The condition is `i < size` not `i <= size`. Also if you need to count all numbers divisible by 3 or 5 between  0 and 1000 your counting statement should be simply `count++;`

Comment: I'm confused because `233168` is the correct answer to Project Euler 1, but you seem to think `232169` is correct.  Your program with `size = 999` was off by one because the loop did not reach `999`.

Comment: @JS1 I think substituting the `count`  variable name with `sum` might also enlighten from some confusion.

Comment: there are only a couple of valid signatures for the `main()` function.  They all have a return type of `int`.  The signature for the `main()` function is the posted code is not correct.

Comment: _@Soha_ As a side note: To learn programming you shouldn't attend to online coding contests like project euler, hackerrank, codechef or similar. These are a complete waste of time, and all you will learn is about bad coding habits. Better get a good beginners book or online tutorial to achieve knowledge about a programming language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've learnt programming, that part is over, now, I'm practicing.

Comment: @all I was confused. This is not really a problem, I've edited the question.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine After your edit, your question is even more _off-topic_ for code review. Relying on what was asked in Project Euler #1 your output should be right for that task.  As an improvement I could only mention that you should rename `count` to `sum` for clarity, and you should leave out the redundant initialization of `i`. Also what  _@user3629249_ mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code [appears to be broken](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3650#3650).  If you work on it a bit more, and get it working correctly, we'd love to review it then. Thanks!

Comment: @user3629249 I know this is not valid C, but my compiler ignores this. I'm a lazy person, I like to type less. Hence, not using int before main().

Comment: When you edit the question, also please make sure to describe the problem that the code is intended to solve.  Just a reference or even a link to the online problem is not sufficient here on Code Review.  I'd also recommend making the code as good as you can get it *first*, and *then* asking for a code review.

Comment: @Edward My coding was all right, I was just a little confused - that's all.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to get it more on topic.  If the question is reopened, perhaps you'll get some reviews.  Meanwhile, I'd suggest studying [the help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to gain a better understanding of how Code Review is intended to work.

Comment: @Edward Thanks! I really appreciate your support. I'm sorry if I've caused any kind of inconvenience to the community.

Comment: It's not a problem -- we were all beginners once!  Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: you state your compiler ignores problems in the code!.  Two possible suggestions: 1) turn ON all warnings when compiling.  If #1 is not possible, then 2) get a modern compiler (versions of `gcc` can be obtained for free  online  and some version is available for almost any CPU

Comment: I'm using DEV C++.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code contains a logic problem.

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int size=1000, i=0, sum=0;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (i%3==0 || i%5==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

will increment the `sum` variable when `i` is 0 (0%x is 0)

So that logic problem needs to be corrected.

You cannot be sloppy with coding.  So fix the signature for `main()`